# arranging vectors in 3-space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've been having a little trouble visualising this so I post here to try to get some help. I need to find 4 vectors in 3-space so the dot product of any two is negative. I thought there could only be a maximum of three vectors as if we evenly place four vectors around in 3-space the maximum separation angle is pi/2, which gives a non-negative dot product. I guess my assumption that the maximum separation is pi/2 is probably wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the separation is $\frac \pi 2$ the dot product is zero.  You need the separations to be strictly greater than $\frac \pi 2$.  The maximum for four vectors is $\frac \pi 2$ in two dimensions, but a third dimension gives more flexibility.  Think of the four vectors from the center of a regular tetrahedron to the corners, for example.

Comment: Thanks. On a related note, what approach should I use to prove that I cannot arrange 5 vectors, all with non-negative dot products? I've just found something that is called the 'simplex' which I think could be useful.

Comment: You must mean you cannot arrange five with negative dot products.  Five (or any number) with positive dot products are easy:  just take them all in (almost) the same direction. Each vector eliminates a hemisphere for any other vector.  Two vectors must eliminate at least.$3/4$ of the sphere and there is only room for two others in the remaining wedge.

Comment: I mean more specifically in the sense that if you take $any$ two vectors the dot product is negative. Your explanation doesn't help me comprehend why I can do it for four vectors but not for five.

Comment: Yes, I was reading the problem that the dot product should be negative between any two vectors.  If you think of the earth, we might as well have the first vector point from the center to the north pole.  Now we can't have any other vector pointing into the northern hemisphere or it would have positive dot product with the first.  We might as well have the second along the line of 0 degrees longitude somewhere.  If we want to exclude the minimum amount of new space, it should point just barely south of the equator, where it will eliminate another quarter of the surface area of the earth.

Comment: It would help to get a ball and mark the points.  After you have placed the first two vectors you have a remaining area shaped like ().  The two ends are over $\frac \pi 2$ apart, so you can place two vectors in it making four.  There isn't room for three.